# Should links into my global website point to the language subdirectory or to the root URL which auto-redirects to the correct language?

Tags: seo, redirects, backlinks, language, technical-seo

I have a global project. This website contains `/en` and `/tr` pages. The home page redirects to the country where it is located with a 302 redirect. If it is not available in both countries, it will be redirected to `/en`.

I will now get a backlink from an English forum. When getting a link should I get it as `https://example.com/`  or should I get it as `https://example.com/en`  ?

Comment: I will omit it, as the user experience counts the most and tells eg Google that it is the main language. However, you should not omit /en if Turkish is the main language. Basic SEO is about making it easy to interpret and index websites. It will therefore not be in your interest to appear as a site that addresses itself in English, while Turkish is most pronounced on the site.

Comment: @diblo-dk Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, links should point to the final URL that the user sees.  You shouldn't create links to redirecting URLs.

If a forum is in English, its readers are going to expect pages in links to also be in English.  The link should point to `https://example.com/en.`

While links to your home page can be good for SEO, they are usually less valuable than deep links to specific content.  So having links to specific pages like `https://example.com/en/page.html` is better than having all the links to the home page.

When creating links to your own site, you need to be very careful to avoid the appearance of spamming.   Creating spammy links to your own site is a sure way to hurt SEO.  You should follow these guidelines:

- Only create links when the topic of the thread matches the topic of your site.
- You should join the forum conversation rather than just posting a link.
- Links to your site are only going to valuable to SEO when they are appreciated by the community in which you are posting.   If other people thank you for the resource, or otherwise react positively, that is a sign that you are not going to be considered spammy.
- You should create only a handful of links to your own site.  Creating tens or hundreds of links really looks spammy.
- Create links over time.   Creating one link a week for several weeks looks a lot better than creating five on the same day.
- Avoid putting links in forum signatures and tag lines.  Search engines tend to discount those links.

Comment: Actually that was the answer I wanted. Really thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

> The home page redirects to the country where it is located with a 302
> redirect. If it is not available in both countries, it will be
> redirected to /en.

This is contrary to **[Google's recommendations](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/managing-multi-regional-sites)**:

> **Let the user switch the page language**
>
> If you have multiple versions of
> a page:
>
> Consider adding hyperlinks to other language versions of a page. That
> way users can click to choose a different language version of the
> page. Avoid automatic redirection based on the user's perceived
> language. These redirections could prevent users (and search engines)
> from viewing all the versions of your site.

and

> Do not use IP analysis to adapt your content. IP location analysis is
> difficult and generally not reliable. Furthermore, Google may not be
> able to crawl variations of your site properly. Most, but not all,
> Google crawls originate from the US, and we do not attempt to vary the
> location to detect site variations. Use one of the explicit methods
> shown here (hreflang, alternate URLs, and explicit links).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I know google's guidelines. There is already a language switch section on my website. Unfortunately I have to do this as I have no other choice. My question is should I get it as `https://example.com/` when getting backlink or should I get it from the link of the country where I will get that backlink?

Comment: Google's guidlines against redirects are for content pages.   You don't want to automatically redirect away from a page in one language to a page in another language.   It is fine to auto-redirect based on language for the root URL that won't have content in any case.   The only change I would recommend would be to have a fall back page with links to every language when the language can't be determined rather than treating one language as the default.

Comment: @stephen-ostermiller You are truly great. :)